# Plotting a composition of the logarithm function (base 10) and a linear function

Tags: tikz-pgf

What is the code to represent a logarithm to the base 10?  I would like to graph

> y = log_{10}(3x + 1)

on the interval [-0.1, 6].

I would also like to graph the tangent line to the graph at (3, 1).  The equation is

> y = [3/(10 * ln(10))](x - 3) + 1.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}

%http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf

\begin{document}

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,
    domain=-10:10, samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-2.5,ymax=2.5,
    restrict y to domain=-2.5:2.5,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-0.1:6,blue] {log(3x + 1)} node[above,pos=0.9]{$\scriptstyle{y} = f(x)$};
\draw [fill] (3,1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
\vskip0.2in


\end{document}
```

Comment: The function for the logarithm to base 10 is `log10`. Note that you need specify multiplication specifically, so you have to say `3*x`, not just `3x`.

Comment: @Jake Yes, I did find that mistake.  I guess that if I wanted to plot the logarithmic function to the base 2, I would code `log3(x).`

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}

%http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf

\begin{document}

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,
    domain=-10:10, samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-2.5,ymax=2.5,
    restrict y to domain=-2.5:2.5,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-0.1:6,blue] {log10(3*x + 1)} node[above,pos=0.9]{$\scriptstyle{y} = f(x)$};
\addplot[samples=3,domain=-0.1:6,red] {(x-3)*3/(10*ln(10))+1};
\draw [fill] (3,1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
\vskip0.2in


\end{document}
```

[image]

For the sake of mathematics: alternatively, using

[image]

you get the same thing by:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}

%http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf

\begin{document}

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,
    domain=-10:10, samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-2.5,ymax=2.5,
    restrict y to domain=-2.5:2.5,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-0.1:6,blue] {ln(3*x + 1)/ln(10)} node[above,pos=0.9]{$\scriptstyle{y} = f(x)$};
\addplot[samples=3,domain=-0.1:6,red] {(x-3)*3/(10*ln(10))+1};
\draw [fill] (3,1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
\vskip0.2in


\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `ln(x)/ln(10)`,  you can simply use `log10(x)`.

Comment: @Jake Just could'nt resist to add a nice formula ... :-)

Comment: @Jake As you can see from my code, I did use `ln(x)/ln(10)` for the logarithmic function to the base 10.  I looked in the manual for the code for plotting logarithmic functions.  I did not find `log10(x)` for plotting the logarithmic function to the base 10. Thanks.

Comment: @Adelyn: I'm not sure I understand your comment. A list of the mathematical functions defined in the PGF math engine (which is the engine used in PGFPlots) can be found in the [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), currently on page 935. Three logarithmic functions are defined: `ln`, `log10`, and `log2`.

Comment: @Jake Yep.  Three logarithmic functions are defined in PGFPlots; the others have to be defined in terms of one of these three functions using the Change-of-Base Formula.  I looked in the manual for any mention of "log."  This word is mentioned hundreds of times, and the first hundred times is in the context of the axes.  It was too frustrating to keep looking in the manual.  My computer is slow, too. It needs about 15 seconds to load each page.  I stopped when I was on page 150 - or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for a nice graph, with the vertical asymptote.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3,xmax=10,
    domain=-10:10, samples=501,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-5,ymax=3,
    restrict y to domain=-5:3,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=251,latex-latex,domain=-2.5:10, thin] {(3/(10 * ln(10))) * x - 9/(10 * ln(10)) + 1};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-0.333:9,blue] {(1/ln(10)) * ln(3*x + 1)}
node[pos=0.9, anchor=north, font=\footnotesize] {$y=\log(3x + 1)$};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex, samples=251,domain=-5:3] (-1/3,x) node[pos=0.1, anchor=south, font=\footnotesize, sloped] {$x=-\frac{1}{3}$};
\draw [fill] (3,1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}

\end{document}
```